# Extracting filename from path in bash using 'basename -s'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Can anyone explain the following code:

```
for var in $1\*.html
    echo $( basename -s .html $var )
done
```

What does `-s` do? Does it strip off the .html from each filename?

Comment: Check `man basename`.

Comment: Btw.: add a `do`.

Comment: Why do we need to add a `do`?

Comment: Maybe [`basename(1)` man page](https://www.google.com/search?q=basename++man+page) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-s suffix` option means that `basename` removes the suffix from the filename, if present.

For example:

```
file=path/to/file.html
basename "$file"          => yields file.html
basename -s .html "$file" => yields file
basename -s  html "$file" => yields file.
basename -s .txt  "$file" => yields file.html since the string has no .txt extension
```

Not sure why you have `$1\*.html` in your for loop - that suppresses the glob expansion and just yields the file that has a literal `*.html` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `$1\*.html` is there for command line input from the user for the directory in which the html files are to be checked.